# Magento Mass Order, Product and Customer Creation

Tags: php, magento, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've created a module in Magento that replicates large stores by creating random products, orders and customers. The data creation described above takes place in my model which is straight PHP code. I'm experiencing serious memory management issues despite making use of PHP's unset() and Magento's clearInstance(). I've commented ~10 lines of code below showing how my attempt to free memory fails.

```
/**
 * Creates random customers.
 *
 * @param  int $offset, used to make sure the ids created are unique
 */
protected function _createCustomer($offset)
{
    // Create some random customer information
    $firstName = strtolower($_firstNames[array_rand($_firstNames, 1)]);
    $lastName  = strtolower($_lastNames[array_rand($_lastNames, 1)]);
    $customerEmail = $firstName[0] . $lastName.time().$offset."@weliketopumpit.com";

    // Retrieve customer model
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId())
        ->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

    // Populate model and save it
    if(!$customer->getId()){
        $customer
            ->setEmail    ($customerEmail)
            ->setFirstname($firstName)
            ->setLastname ($lastName)
            ->setPassword ('password1')
            ->setCreatedAt(rand($this->_startDate, time()));
    }
    $customer->save();
    $customer->setConfirmation(null);
    $customer->save();

    $this->log(memory_get_usage() . "\n"); // Returns 17306840
    $customer->clearInstance();            // Called to clean up the object
    $this->log(memory_get_usage());        // Returns 17307304, memory wasn't unallocated

    debug_zval_dump($customer);            //Returns a refcount(2)
}
```

Calling unset in place of clearInstance() produces the same result. Any tips on how to clean up after using Magento models?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the resource instead of the model, it's gonna be quicker and less memory costly. If that's not good enough, convert it to raw sql, EAV is not that complex when it comes to inserting records.

An alternative way I would also try is: http://ringsdorff.net/2009/07/23/guest-post-fix-for-memory-leaks-in-magento/
But that's not recommended for production, so I would build a custom Customer model that incorporates those desctructors and just use the new model in my script leaving everything else (production) run on normal model.